# Implement Auto Redirect on Session Idle timeout using Azure AD and OAuth2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, session-cookies

Our application is using SSO (single sign-on) feature for user authentication which is checking user identity from Azure Active Directory.

We have configured a `SSO` in `Configure Services()` method of `Startup.cs` class, here we use `AddCookie()` and set the expiration time as **29** minutes.

As per as my understanding SSO implementation using `Ouath2.0` redirects user automatically after set cookie expiration idle time period finished.
I may be wrong here as it is not working as expected, session is not getting expired even after hours of Idle time.

Could anyone please check below code implementation and suggest changes for acheiving the required functionality?

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //configure my sso
    MySsoProvider.ConfigureSso(services, Configuration);

    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
    //initialize azure provider
    services.AddTransient(CreateAzureBlobFileProvider);
    //ad app insight telemetry
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
}
        
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
    });
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    AzureStorageAccount.Load(Configuration);
}
```

**MySsoProvider.cs:**

```
public static void ConfigureSso(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "PingCookie";
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = "PingCookie";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Ping";
    }).AddCookie("PingCookie", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, 29, 0);
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 29, 0); //cookie exipration set to 29 minutes
    }).AddOAuth("Ping", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["abc-def-sso-clientid"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["abc-def-sso-secret"];

        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-ping");

        options.Scope.Add("openid profile email");
        options.UsePkce = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["Ping:AuthorizationEndpoint"];
        options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["Ping:TokenEndpoint"];
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["Ping:UserInformationEndpoint"];

        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "immutable_id");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:openid:groups", "groups");

        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var user = JsonDocument.Parse(responseText);
                context.RunClaimActions(user.RootElement);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

**Required Functionality:**

- We are looking for user to automatically redirect to other page when
  application is idle for 30 minutes (User do not perform any actions)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can try by making small changes in configurattion as below  by setting  UseTokenLifetime , Sliding expiration  etc :

According to [Configure ASP.NET Core Identity | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cookie-settings)
,ConfigureApplicationCookie must be called after calling AddIdentity or AddDefaultIdentity.

In place of CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme of services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme), if you have 'Cookies' authentication scheme use as below:

```js
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = " Cookies ";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Ping";
    }).AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
    {
    options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
    options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan. FromMinutes(29);
    (or) //options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(29);
    
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(29);
    
    });
```

If SlidingExpiration is set to true then the cookie would be re-issued on any request half way through the ExpireTimeSpan

(Either look for a persistent cookie or increase session timeout.)

In login page make [IsPersistent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#persistent-cookies) to true:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties
{
IsPersistent = true,
RedirectUri = "/Auth/Login",
ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(29)
});
```

set it to false for the cookie to behave like Session

**References:**

1. [Cookie authentication in aspnet core3.0 no working (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a687101-f7a6-41d6-ae29-0c063a9b6727/cookie-authentication-in-aspnet-core30-no-working)
2. [ASP.NET Core 3.1 application with Identity logging off quickly -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459294/asp-net-core-3-1-application-with-identity-logging-off-quickly)